# looping through text chars

Tags: vb.net, loops, text

I am trying to capture a string from a textbox and run a condition based upon each character found in that string. The following code is what I'm thinking in but it dosnt work?

```
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text

        For Each c As Char In s
            If c = "A" Then
                MsgBox("Letter is A")
            ElseIf c = "B" Then
                MsgBox("Letter is A")
            ElseIf c = "C" Then
                MsgBox("Letter is C")

            End If
        Next
end sub
```

Comment: in what way it doesn't work?

Comment: If you're capable of hitting either the `A,B or C` key when `TextBox1` is focused and then press `Button1` this will work.

Comment: Doh! Your right it works Stuipid me left msgbox for letter B to indicate an A my wrong....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use chararry to split it, your  text box is probbly capteruring some unicode

```
Dim charArray() As Char = TextBox1.Text.ToCharArray
```

also look at the msdn page great insights[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233830.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim stringword() As Char
    stringword = TextBox1.Text.ToCharArray
    For i = 0 To stringword.Count - 1
        Select Case stringword(i)
            Case "a", "A"
                MsgBox("Letter is A")
            Case "B", "b"
                MsgBox("Letter is b")
            Case "C", "c"
                MsgBox("Letter is c")

        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```